# Setting a text area as non editable in jsp based on a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am writing a jsp code in which has a dropdown list and a text area. However the text area should only be editable on a particular value of the dropdown list. Please tell me how to do this....

Answer (score 0):

You can make textarea disabed/enabled manipulating with textarea's `disabled` attribute in javascript.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/GsSWZ/) to play arround with.